# Decrypting AES-128-ECB, first character decrypts to 4 bytes

Tags: php, ios, aes, mcrypt

I have an iOS app that is encrypting a string using [NSData AES128EncryptWithKey:] and sending it via HTTP. We did not write the app, and why it's not just using HTTPS and instead using HTTP with AES-128 bit encryption - I have no idea. I know it's not ideal but I'm working with what the client has given me and as of right NOW I have no ability/authority to fix that.

I am charged with writing a server app to take this data that is being sent as a raw binary HTTP POST and decrypting the POST body and then working on that sent data. I'm using PHP as it's the language I can write the server side in fastest (I am modifying a similar server app that already does the work we need it to do. The last use the data was not encrypted and was sent over HTTPS)

When I decrypt the string using either mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128) or openssl_decrypt (AES-128-ECB), using the developer supplied 16 byte key, the first character of the string is expanded to 4 bytes, all wrong, and the rest of the string decrypts just fine. The string begins with username=WHATEVER and then has about 700 bytes of other data behind it (total length is a multiple of 16, it's padded server-side correctly as best I can tell). The entire string is correct, but when decrypted, what I get is:

```
o@{asername=WHATEVER...
```

Every search I've made tells me about a bad 16 bytes when using AES-CBC with the wrong IV, but it decrypts correctly with ECB - just the first byte is wrong, and expanded to 4 bytes.

What am I missing?

Comment: That sounds like a length prefix.

Comment: Please add php sample code for decryption including real input data and expected value of decrypted data.

Comment: There are two possibilities: it's padding to align the data to 16 bytes (but it usually is added at the end by the algorithm) or it's an indicator with the content length to check the size, try to read it as a binary integer.

Comment: Look at the decrypted data as hex and see exactly what is happening. Add that to the question. Sorry, hex is still needed for many things.

Comment: The only professional solution is to refuse to write and/or maintain insecure code. Just stand firm that security comes first and fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Based on comments about a length prefix, I checked the known string length vs the decrypted string length and it was off by 20 or so characters. Seems the front was padded with some binary data, that when printed to a terminal screen resulted in null characters and somehow erased characters that came after it (the missing 'u' in username)? When I did a substr($data, 20) the string printed correctly. The first 20 bytes, not sure what exactly that is, but I found the data I needed. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't understand the data you can not create a correct solution. My bet is that the 20 bytes is a SHA-1 authentication check. ECB mode is insecure, don't use it.